# Add a line break when sharing a text with the charm bar

Tags: c#, windows-8, charms-bar

For a Windows 8 App, in C#/Xaml, I am using the charm bar to share some content.

My problem is that I don't see my carriage returns in the text I want to share in the sharing application.

For example I want to share :

```
 Hello,

 Read this article about blablabla

 GoodBye
```

And on the email application in the charm bar it is displayed :

```
 Hello,Read this article about blablabla GoodBye
```

I tried to put some \n or %0d%0a or Environment.NewLine, but without any success...

How can I solve this problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sending an email, you could use `HTML`.

```
string message = "<p>Hello,</p><p>Read this article about blablabla</p>
                                                             <p>GoodBye</p>";
string htmlMessage = HtmlFormatHelper.CreateHtmlFormat(message);
request.Data.SetHtmlFormat(htmlMessage);
```

Of course, being `HTML`, you can use more advanced formatting and also include images. There's a full example of using the HTML format on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh973055%28v=win.10%29.aspx).